# How do I move individual letters up and down?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-word-2016

Let's say I have the word cake and I want to move the "a" higher and the "e" lower (about 1pt each).

Is there any way to shift them up and down without messing with the paragraph settings (which changes the rules whole line)? I remember I had a macro on my Word 2003 which did just that, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Select "a", then press Ctrl+D (Font dialog box) and go to Advanced tab. Then change Position to Raised (or Lowered) and set appropriate point size.